# An extra dot after section counter while numbering equations

Tags: sectioning, equations, numbering, punctuation

My sections are numbered with a dot after counter. I get it like this

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
```

I also need the equations to be numbered within sections and I try to do it like this

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

The result is that I get numbers of equations with an extra dot, e.g. `(1..1)` instead of `(1.1)`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add a closing dot the the definition of `\thesection`, you should also remove the "middle" dot from definitions using `\thesection`, especially `\theequation` and `\thesubsection`. (Note that your redefinition of `\thesection` will also produce a closing dot in the table of contents, the header/footer, and cross references.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\subsection{bar}

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: In response to Frank Mittelbach, here's an alternative that changes the `\@seccntformat` macro so that it adds a dot if the new `\@seccntdot` conditional is true. The [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package is used to set this conditional to true before `\section` and to false after every equal/lower-level sectioning command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\newif\if@seccntdot

\pretocmd{\section}{\@seccntdottrue}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@xsect}{\@seccntdotfalse}{}{}

\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \if@seccntdot .\fi
  \quad
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\subsection{bar}

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output for both examples:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As it was already mentioned by @lockstep changing `\thesection` in this manner means that the extra dot is added whereever `\thesection`is being used (which is in various places) and for example in cross references or in the TOC this is probably not desired.

One possible alternative is to change the command `\@seccntformat` which is used by the standard heading commands to format the number of th heading itself (but nowhere else). Its default definition is

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

The dot could be easily added there, however it would then apply to all headings produced with `\@startsection`, e.g., `\section`, `\subsection`, ... unless you build in some logic that provides different results depending on the  argument.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple alternative is to use a feature of the »[titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)« package to add the dot to the heading.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % loads »amsmath«
\usepackage{titlesec}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
  \section{Foo}
    \subsection{Bar}

      \begin{equation}
        a^2+b^2=c^2
      \end{equation}
\end{document}
```